# How to define specific ranges in python

Tags: python, function, range

I’m struggling to create a function where the program will identify if 3 values are within a certain sub-range of a larger range.

If all 3 values are within the same larger range and sub-range: Print (“my message”)

For example, I have a variable called `last3_values` which takes the most recent 3 previous values from a DF (not the realtime value).

This information is updated realtime, so if `last3_values` are say 200, 277, 236, they are ‘similar’ in value as they fall into the larger range 100’s and sub-range 200-299.

The larger ranges are Hundreds 100’s Thousands 1000’s Tens of thousands 10000’s

So the subranges would follow suit like 200-299, 9000-9999 or 15000-15999 etc I fear I am overcomplicating it somewhere in my script but don’t have the experience to fully figure this out without some guidance. Really appreciate it, thanks.

With the executive assistance of chatgpt I tried the function below.
Firstly, apologies for using chatgpt ha!

```
def get_specific_range(delta_values):
    abs_delta = abs(delta_values)
    str_delta = str(abs_delta)
    length = len(str_delta)

    # For values in the 10's
    if length == 1 or (length == 2 and abs_delta < 100):
        return 0, 99  # The range for 0-99

    # For values in the hundreds
    elif length == 3:
        prefix = int(str_delta[0])  # Get the hundred's digit
        return prefix * 100, (prefix + 1) * 100 - 1

    # For values in the thousands
    elif length == 4:
        prefix = int(str_delta[:2])  # Get the first two digits
        return prefix * 1000, (prefix + 1) * 1000 - 1

    # For values in the ten thousands
    elif length == 5:
        prefix = int(str_delta[:3])  # Get the first three digits
        return prefix * 10000, (prefix + 1) * 10000 - 1

    else:
        return None
```

I feel like it could be something really simple and my lack of experience and heavy use of AI is hindering the continuation of my work so humbling myself here.

Comment: No, the AI is doing you no favors.  That function only takes a single number, and over complicates things by converting to string.  Instead of `length == 3` and `int(str_delta[0]` you could use `100 <= delta_values <= 999` and `delta_values // 100`.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the reply this looks much simpler thank you. May I ask, how would I then get the program to check for this function and print message? Rather how do I call this function to allow the program to print relevant messages. Hope im making sense

Comment: If you don't know how to call a function and print the values it returns, you should be taking a class or reading a tutorial that teaches it to you.  A certain minimum amount of expertise is assumed from people who ask a question here.

Comment: I did initially write on my post I was new to coding, but it was edited out. I managed to do it however, with your suggestion so thanks again